# How to have msbuild copy files to output directory across references?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

Suppose we have a project `A` with output directory `bin/` and a project `B` with output directory `test/bin/`. Project `A` needs to have a certain configuration file copied to its output directory. Currently, this is being done by adding a pre-build event that looks like

```
COPY /Y "$(ProjectDir)..\config.ini" "$(TargetDir)"
```

Project `B` has `A` as dependency. When project `B` builds, the binary resulting from `A` is correctly copied to the output directory of `B`, but the config file isn't!

How can we achieve that all files that `A` needs to have are also copied to the output directory of `B`?

Comment: This just isn't necessary when you leave the Output Directory settings at their default value.  Fighting the build system is your prerogative, but you'll have to help when you do.  You already know how to use COPY.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is a [Link File](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306234).  I've used these before to ensure that connection.config files are copied to multiple projects.

I created a sample solution that mimics your described scenario as seen below.  The `ConsoleApplication1` references the `ClassLibrary1` project.  In the solution, I created a solution folder `config` and added the shared config that needs to be copied.

[image: solution example]

In order to have a single file that is copied across multiple projects, you must create a single file, and then add it as a link to the projects that need it.  This can be done by right clicking on the project, and choosing `Add -> Existing Item...`.  You will see a dialog as show below and you want to choose the `Add as Link` option from the dropdown instead of just `Add`.

[image: add link example]

Finally, edit the properties for the linked file to copy it to the output directory.

[image: properties example]

Comment: The question is about C++, not C#